# Shorter output from systemctl status

Tags: systemctl

Is there a way to get shorter/custom output from systemctl status? I really only need the active line prepended with the name of the service. So something like this:

```
        apache2: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:42 +03; 16min ago
        mongodb: inactive (dead)  since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:47 +03; 16min ago
rabbitmq-server: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:52 +03; 16min ago
 mongodb-server: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:54 +03; 16min ago
          mysql: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:57 +03; 16min ago
```

only with color feedback. But I would settle for it without color. Or on two lines plus a blank line like:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:42 +03; 16min ago

● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:47 +03; 16min ago

● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:52 +03; 16min ago

● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:54 +03; 16min ago

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 17:20:57 +03; 16min ago
```

This kind of satisfies the latter btw:

```
systemctl status apache2.service mongodb.service \
redis.service rabbitmq-server.service mysql.service | grep -e Active -e ●
```

But it messes up the colors doesn't have the whitespace and I kind of expect there is a systemctl option or configuration somewhere where I can get exactly what I want.

Comment: While not exactly what you need, I get by with adding `-n 0` to show zero journal lines in `systemctl status $SERVICE`

Answer (score 7):

So there's no native way in `systemctl` to format the output in this way, but we can do it anyways by getting a bit creative with pipes.

First, we need a list of all running services on the system:

```
# systemctl -t service --state=running --no-legend --no-pager

accounts-daemon.service                         loaded active running Accounts Service                                               
atd.service                                     loaded active running Deferred execution scheduler                                   
containerd.service                              loaded active running containerd 
...
```

No time output. To get that we have to invoke `systemctl show` against the unit with the `--property=ActiveEnterTimestamp` flag. Example:

```
# systemctl show accounts-daemon.service --property=ActiveEnterTimestamp
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Wed 2019-12-11 21:44:50 UTC
```

Now if only we had a way to staple that output onto the end of the `systemctl` output.. we do!

This is an ugly one-liner, but it gets the job done:

```
systemctl -t service --state=running --no-legend --no-pager | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | while read f; do STARTTIME=`systemctl show $f 
--property=ActiveEnterTimestamp | sed 's/ActiveEnterTimestamp=//'`; echo "$f $STARTTIME"; done`
```

To explain:

- The `cut` command is splitting on spaces and taking the first field from `systemctl`, which is the service name.
- We enter a while loop that pipes that service name into a variable named `$f`
- We create a variable named `STARTTIME` that contains the `systemctl show` output with the start time flag.
- We use `sed` to strip the actual `ActiveEnterTimestamp=` text, giving us the time only.
- Finally, we `echo` the service name and the cleaned up start time, separated with a space.

The final output looks like this:

```
accounts-daemon.service Wed 2019-12-11 21:44:50 UTC
atd.service Wed 2019-12-11 21:44:48 UTC
containerd.service Wed 2019-12-11 21:44:50 UTC
```